# Understanding Ansible's conditional expressions

Tags: ansible

I am struggling to understand some ansible behaviour, and although I have resolved the problem at hand, I'm curious if anyone can shed light on *why* ansible is behaving the way it does.

I have stripped the extraneous details of the task out, and boiled it down to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/PhilipHarries/1e985c122b259a4ac17a).

The problem appears when passing variables in as booleans such as:

```
ansible-playbook -i ./local.hosts ./test.yml -e "x=true y=false z=false"
```

I can use these variables in `when` clauses, and they work as expected:

```
 - name: do_something_if_x_is_true
   shell: echo kill all humans
   when: x
```

To me this seems to demonstrate that `x` has been passed in, and parsed, as a boolean.  But as soon as `x` is used in a compound condition, `(x and y)` - everything goes wrong, and the variables stop behaving.

To resolve the issue, I can cast x explicitly as a boolean:

```
 - name: do_something_when_x_and_y_are_true
   shell: echo finally robotic beings rule the world
   when: (x|bool and y|bool)
```

And great, everything works as I expect.

I'd really like to understand this behaviour, can anyone explain?

Answer (score 4):

Vars passed on the command-line don't go through the YAML parser, which is what normally does the boolean type inference. In the absence of that, or some other hint (like the bool filter), they're just strings to Jinja. Jinja's a pretty thin wrapper over Python, and Python says any non-empty string is True. In the situation below, the YAML parser does the boolean type inference, since the vars are defined inline:

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    x: false
    y: false
  tasks:
  - name: do_something_if_x_is_true
    shell: echo kill all humans
    when: x or y
  # humans are safe!
```

For safety, if you don't know where your vars are coming from, it's probably a good idea to use the bool filters.

Comment: I'm sure this is the answer - thank you.  There is a remaining question in my mind though - which is why do my variables x, y, z get interpreted as I expect ("true" is true, and "false" is false - without the boolean filter) - when used on their own (not in a compound expression).  I'm guessing that there's an attempt to parse a single variable as an expression that isn't made when it's part of a compound.  Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure they really do- at least in the sample you showed, "x" will always be true for a non-empty string, same as (x or y) so long as x and y are non-empty. Check your test case again with the explanation in mind- I think you'll find it's consistent.

Comment: I think that you answer is consistent and accurate, but doesn't address the specific oddity I'm seeing.  Why is ( y and true) true, when y is false?  I've crystallised it further to a new gist:  https://gist.github.com/PhilipHarries/2b6c0aae7fb8bdd4d66c  Comments would be appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at this gist: at least in Ansible 1.9.2, it behaves exactly as I'd expect (fewer moving parts than yours, but should demo the same thing): https://gist.github.com/nitzmahone/df1d47525982c7c9f02c

Comment: I'm using Ansible 1.9.2 also.  When I run your gist, I get the expected behaviour based on your explanation (thank you) - i.e. they are interpreted as strings, and "false" is considered True.  However, it doesn't test the case where we just have 'x' and 'y' on their own in the when clause - which (at least when I test it) behave differently.  In that case, "true"(string) is True, and "false"(string) is False.  In other words, I think that "x and True" should always be equivalent to "x" - but it isn't...